# Numericupdown as 0.00 in c#

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I need that numericUpDown as 0.00 format i don't know how to make numericUpDown as 0.00

when i make increment in numericUpDown it increment like this `1.00 , 2.00 ......n.00`

[image]

[image]

when i make decrement

it gives -1.00 , -2.00 ....-n.00

[image]

[image]

How do i make numericUpDown like this format help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `DecimalPlaces` for the numericUpDown1 otherwise the default value `0` will be taken, Like wise you have to specify the `.Increment` also otherwise the default value `1` will be evaluated. Now see the How to set these :

```
numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2;
numericUpDown1.Increment = 0.01M;
```

More notes on [NumericUpdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm mark your answer as accepted answer, but it gives me an time to accept. your answers is accepted after 10 min of your answer time.

Comment: thank u for your answer you saves my time thank you.